# swapped eth for utk on uniswap- etherscan shows completed but uniswap still pending and i utk doesn't show in wallet!

Tags: metamask, uniswap

help anyone?  i'm new to uniswap.  i swapped out eth for utk and my transcation was "dropped and replaced" by transaction hash 0xd167827dfe353c65b94c2a3673ea74deaa4f8762be771a87f7bf9942d06ef29a

i've tried restarting my browser and also restarting my metamask app and nothing.

It shows that the transaction was completed but on uniswap, it still says pending and i don't see my UTK coins in my metamask wallet!  thank you in advance for schooling a noob.

Comment: I dont see any problem. You have 10,554 tokens of UTK

Comment: i figured it out.  metamask did not automatically recognize the utk coin in my wallet so i had to import it using the address so now my wallet reflects it correctly!   uniswap still says pending though lol.  hope someone else will benefit from this  thanks for your help!